# Is this proof valid for $A\subset B \implies A \cap B = A$?

Tags: proof-verification, alternative-proof

First semester for me. I need to prove the following:

> If $A \subset B \implies A \cap B = A$.

I tried some simpler versions which don't quite satisfy me. So I tried the following:

Given $x \in A \cap B, A \subset B$ and $(A \cap B) \setminus A \neq \varnothing \implies \,\exists x \in (A \cap B) \setminus A : x \notin A \implies x \notin A \cap B$

Which is a contradiction. So $(A \cap B) \setminus A = \varnothing \implies A \cap B = A$

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $(A\cap B)\setminus A=\emptyset$ is always true regardless of whether or not $A\cap B=A$.  For example $A=\{1\}, B=\{2\}$ one has $(A\cap B)\setminus A = \emptyset$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset\neq \{1\}=A$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let A $\subset$ B.

We show A $\cap$ B $\subset$ A.  Suppose x$\in$ A $\cap$ B. By definition of intersection, x $\in$ A and x $\in$ B.  So x $\in$ A. Thus A $\cap$ B $\subset$ A.

We now show A $\subset$ A $\cap$ B.  Since A $\subset$ B by assumption, $\forall$ x $\in$ A, x $\in$ B. Thus $\forall$ x $\in$ A, x $\in$ A $\cap$ B. Thus A $\subset$ A $\cap$ B.

Therefore, A = A $\cap$ B.

Comment: Yes, this is nearly what I could come up with myself. But would the one above be valid, too?

Comment: Not really, you are assuming a contradiction that the intersection contains no element of A. The only A for which this would hold, which is still a subset of B is the empty set.

Comment: You can always try to prove the contrapositive.